# Expressing point charge density in terms of the spherical harmonics

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, multipole-expansion

Lets suppose we have two point charges at for $q(0,0,+a)$ and $-q(0,0,-a)$. We can express this as the charge density, by using

$$\rho(\vec{r})=q\delta(r-a)\delta(\phi)[\delta(\theta)-\delta(\theta-\pi/2)]$$

Now, is there a way to express this in terms of spherical harmonics, $Y_{\ell m}(\Omega)$? Since I need to find:

$$A_{\ell m}=\frac{4\pi}{2\ell +1}\int d^3r\rho(\vec{r})r^{\ell}Y^*_{\ell m}(\Omega)$$

so that I can find the multipoles.

Comment: Just compute that integral!  It will be easy, because you have a bunch of delta functions.  However, I think your expression for the charge density is wrong, because it doesn't have the right units.  Right now, it has units of charge per length,  when it should have units of charge per volume.  It's likely that you need an extra factor of something like $1/r^2\sin\theta$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: I can understand the $1/r^2$ but not the $sin \theta$. The integral will be easy but what about the $Y_{\ell m}$ terms..

Comment: You just evaluate $Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)$ at $\phi=0$ and ($\theta=0$ or $\theta=\pi/2$) and leave it as, for instance,  $Y_{lm}(0,0)$.  There are likely further simplifications that can occur by actually evaluating $Y_{lm}(0,0)$, but without further context for the problem, it's unclear what simplifications you'd actually want.

Comment: By the way, [a quick search yields this](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~ercelebi/mp03.pdf).